# What is the different between pyspark.sql.functions.avg and pyspark.sql.functions.mean?

Tags: pyspark

From the doc it sounds like they do the same. Is this the case?

Comment: yes, they do the same thing. one is alias to the other.

Comment: keep in mind that Spark is open source so its easy to check it in sources if you are not sure: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L715